# Adobe AIR: Capturing the Desktop and sending to FMS

Tags: air, flash-media-server

Is it possible to do this on Windows, Mac, and Linux? Anyone have example of how to accomplish?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm fairly certain you cannot capture the desktop image in Air without the use of a third party driver or application. Heres a demo using Air with Merapi http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gp2BzQi-gSU

Comment: Not ideal for my application but I think I'll try Merapi